# App closes unexpectedly in absence of network connection

Tags: android, mysql, json

I have made an android login application that verifies username and password from mysql databse, and if they match, open another activity. The app works fine when the device is connected to internet, but when the app is opened in absence of network connection, it closes unexpectedly. Any help would be appreciated. Unfortunately i have developed this in AIDE and cannot post logcat.

MainActivity.java

```
      MainActivity.java
      package com.mycompany.dynamic;
      import java.util.ArrayList;
      import java.util.List;
      import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
      import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
      import org.json.JSONException;
      import org.json.JSONObject; 
      import android.app.Activity;
      import android.app.ProgressDialog;
      import android.content.Intent;
      import android.os.AsyncTask;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.util.Log;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
      import android.widget.Button;
      import android.widget.EditText;
      import android.widget.Toast;
      import android.widget.*;
      import android.graphics.*; 
      public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
             private EditText user, pass;
             private Button bLogin;
              // Progress Dialog
             private ProgressDialog pDialog;

           // JSON parser class
          JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
          private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://necrecords.16mb.com/login.php";
          private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
          private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
             @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
                  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                  setContentView(R.layout.main);      
                  user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
                  pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);          
                  bLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
                TextView tx1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcometv);
                Typeface custom_font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/myfont1.otf");
                tx1.setTypeface(custom_font1);
                TextView tx2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcometexttv);
                Typeface custom_font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/myfont2.ttf");
                tx2.setTypeface(custom_font2);
                  bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
                        }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  switch (v.getId()) {
                  case R.id.login:
                              new AttemptLogin().execute();
                  // here we have used, switch case, because on login activity you may //also want to show registration button, so if the user is new ! we can go the //registration activity , other than this we could also do this without switch //case.
                  default:
                        break;
                  }
            }

            class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
                   /**
               * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
               * */
                  boolean failure = false;

              @Override
              protected void onPreExecute() {
                  super.onPreExecute();
                  pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                  pDialog.setMessage("Attempting for login...");
                  pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                  pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                  pDialog.show();
              }

                  @Override
                  protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         // here Check for success tag
                  int success;
                  String username = user.getText().toString();
                  String password = pass.getText().toString();
                  try {

                      List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                      Log.d("request!", "starting");

                      JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                             LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                      // checking  log for json response
                      Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                      // success tag for json
                      success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                      if (success == 1) {
                        Log.d("Successfully Login!", json.toString());

                        Intent ii = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainMenu.class);
                        finish();
      // this finish() method is used to tell android os that we are done with current //activity now! Moving to other activity
                              startActivity(ii);
                        return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                      }else{

                        return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                      }
                  } catch (JSONException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }

                  return null;
                  }
                  /**
               * Once the background process is done we need to  Dismiss the progress dialog asap
               * **/
              protected void onPostExecute(String message) {

                  pDialog.dismiss();
                  if (message != null){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
              }
            } 
      }
```

JSONParser.java

```
  JSONParser.java
  package com.mycompany.dynamic;
  import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStream;
  import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
  import java.util.List;
  import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
  import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
  import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
  import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
  import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
  import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
  import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
  import org.json.JSONException;
  import org.json.JSONObject;
  import android.util.Log;
  public class JSONParser {
        static InputStream is = null;
        static JSONObject jsonObj ;
        static String json = "";

      // default no argument constructor for jsonpaser class
      public JSONParser() {

      }


      public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

          // Making HTTP request
          try {

              DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
              HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

              // Executing POST request & storing the response from server  locally.
              HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

  HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

              is = httpEntity.getContent();

          } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          try {


              // Create a BufferedReader
           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                      is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
              // Declaring string builder 
              StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
              //  string to store the JSON object.
              String strLine = null;

              // Building while we have string !equal null.
              while ((strLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  str.append(strLine + "\n");
              }

              // Close inputstream.
              is.close();
              // string builder data conversion  to string.
              json = str.toString();
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e("Error", " something wrong with converting result " + e.toString());
          }

          // Try block used for pasrseing String to a json object
          try {
              jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
          } catch (JSONException e) {
              Log.e("json Parsering", "" + e.toString());
          }

          // Returning json Object.
          return jsonObj;

      }



      public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
              List<NameValuePair> params) {

          // Make HTTP request
          try {

              // checking request method
              if(method == "POST"){

                  // now defaultHttpClient object
                  DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                  httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                  HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                  HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                  is = httpEntity.getContent();

              }else if(method == "GET"){
                  // request method is GET
                  DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                  String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                  url += "?" + paramString;
                  HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                  HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                  HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                  is = httpEntity.getContent();
              }           

          } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          try {
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                      is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
              StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
              String strLine = null;
              while ((strLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  str.append(strLine + "\n");
              }
              is.close();
              json = str.toString();
          } catch (Exception e) {

        }

          // now will try to parse the string into JSON object
          try {
              jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
          } catch (JSONException e) {

    }


          return jsonObj;

      }

  }
```

Comment: your code is not working Sanjeet Ajnabee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure working network before you make the call to the server as

```
 if(isNetworkAvailable){
    new AttemptLogin().execute();
     }
```

When no data is received the json parser is not able to parse the data and throwing the exception.
The method for the network availablity may be

```
     public  boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sanjeet Ajnabee

Comment: Can you please modify my code and help me Sanjeet Ajnabee.